# Passing date between pages php and displaying year only

Tags: php, date

I have been passing a user selected date between pages and calling the entire date without any problems.  Now I want to ONLY take the year from the "fromdate" and "todate"  I have got the code below to pass the date

```
<?
        $fromdatePost = $_POST["report_date_from"];
        $todatePost = $_POST["report_date_to"];

        $fromdate = $_POST["report_date_from"] .' 00:00:00';
        $fromdate = preg_replace('#(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})\s(.*)#', '$3-$2-$1 $4', $fromdate);

        $todate = $_POST["report_date_to"] .' 00:00:00';
        $todate = preg_replace('#(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})\s(.*)#', '$3-$2-$1 $4', $todate);  
        ?>
```

Then I display the date by using either of the below

```
'" . $fromdate ."'
```

or

```
'" . $fromdate ."'
```

How do I get it to JUST display the year and not the entire date?!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You must really hate yourself to use regular expressions to format dates.

Comment: you should be using `strtotime` and `date` or `DateTime` functions

Comment: Please see the answer from Tim Burch.
The same thing can be accomplished using the datetime objects PHP now has if you want a slightly more OO method (though honestly stringtotime() is a bit easier to use). If you want the OO let me know and I'll post an answer with it.

Comment: JohnConde Haha! To be honest I have taken over developing a system when I have never used php before!  I have been dropped right in it so trying to learn on the job.  Thanks for the advice cmorrissy and @Mer.  I don't think I have the time to change things but thank you for the offer.  Do you have a link and maybe I can read up for future use?

Comment: no problem: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php
Which is not exactly self explanatory, but if you want to produce the year component of a datetime object do the following (I'll post it as an answer too... for the benefit of any passers-by):
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
    $date = new DateTime();
    echo $date->format('Y');
?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to get the year:

```
$year = date('Y', strtotime($fromdate));
```

To paraphrase the first comment, regular expressions are not necessary here.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I have an additional problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673658/passing-date-from-php-page-to-export-to-excel-document Hope you can help with that too!

Answer (score 1):

The object oriented way to do this is as follows:

```
$date = new DateTime($fromdate);
$year = $date->format('Y');
```

Though I generally feel strtotime is a bit more convenient.
NOTE: If you don't pass any parameters to the DateTime() object it will fill in with the current date & time.